# Throwing 404 response when should be throwing 403

Tags: php, .htaccess, exception, symfony, twig

I have the next rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://itransformer.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpe?g|png|wbmp)$ - [R=403,L]
```

in the main `.htaccess` file.
When anyone try to hotlink an image, he will get a 403 response. However, he's getting a 404 response. If I comment the lines above, I get no error.

Seems to be due to Twig exception templates.

I'm overriding some error templates from Twig exception templates. 
I've successfully overridden the 404 error template by adding the file: `/app/Resources/TwigBundle/views/Exception/error404.html.twig`.

And tried to override the 403 error template. Tried adding: `/app/Resources/TwigBundle/views/Exception/error403.html.twig` but is not shown.

There are not `ErrorDocument` in Apache configuration, neither `.htaccess` files.

**Why is it throwing a 404 response, when it should throw a 403?**

Comment: Can you test : ReWriteRule .*\.(gif|jpe?g|png|wbmp)$ - [F]

Comment: I haven't used apache for some time, but shouldn't your RewriteRule have a URI to redirect to? Or does the '-' character imply something here?

Comment: @Nealio - `-` means no URI redirect. It should just throw a 403 response with no URI redirect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found out the issue:

While `/app/Resources/TwigBundle/views/Exception/` is the framework path to customize exception pages, when the exception comes from an `.htaccess` file or Apache configuration, you must specify the path also into `.htaccess` file or Apache configuration, like this:

```
ErrorDocument 403 /errorTemplatesPath/error403.html.twig
ErrorDocument 404 /errorTemplatesPath/error404.html.twig
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://mysite\.com [NC]
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpe?g|png|wbmp)$ - [NC,F]
```

Comment: Nothing changes with [NC,F] flags. On the other hand, I want to rewrite also when the `HTTP_REFERER` is blank. So the first line should be like at the question.

Comment: Ok edited and removed 1st condition. But if it still throws 404 then it must be due to your framework.

Comment: Probably. But I don't know how to achieve it. I'm doing what the documentation says.